# Naive Bayesian for rating

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, bayesian

Suppose I have a training set that has the following data:

```
Type  |  Size  |   Price  |  Rating  |  SUGGESTION
---------------------------------------------------
Shirt     M        Budget      0           Bad
Trouser   L        Budget      4.2         Good
Shirt     M        Expensive   2.3         Good
....etc....
```

Here am taking `SUGGESTION` as the class that we need to suggest when an input sample is provided. Means, when an input sample(different from the training dataset) is given, we need to figure out whether it is `Good` or `Bad`.

Am able to understand the probability calculation based on an example found from internet:

Dataset: [image: http://i.imgur.com/C0ptard.png]

Calculation for an input sample: [image: http://i.imgur.com/kggEdLJ.png]

The doubt in my dataset is that, I have a column called `Rating`. So, for that column also, we do the probability calculation like the other columns(like in the screenshot above)? Or we need to consider some other way for that one particular column's values? Say like mean and standard deviation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns "Size" and "Price" represent categorical data (well, actually, ordinal, but that's another point). While you do can model "Rating" as categorical value too, it may be bad idea and it'd much better to model your data as numerical. And here's why.

The difference in treating data as categorical and numerical is in different value. Suppose you have 3 observations of x: `x=12`, `x=13`, `x=1344`. The question is then: how much can probabilities `P(x=12)`, `P(x=1344)` and `P(x=13)` differ? The answer heavily depends on what kind of data these values represent.

For example, it `x` denotes user id or something for what ordering is irrelevant, these probabilities can differ arbitrary. But if `x` denotes, say, pay rate, then clearly there's not so much difference between 12 and 13 compared to the third value.

It also helps you to infer more knowledge about your data. For example, there might be no values 4.9 in the dataset, but lots of 4.8 and 5.0. Your model then "interpolates" between these two, giving you a probability for 4.9 even though it wasn't presented in the dataset.

So, yes, you should use numerical distribution (Gaussian, for example) for you rating data. I also suggest to do some cleanup: apparently, 0 stands for "not rated" rather than "extremely bad", so you may want to tell your model about that (for example, replacing 0s with an average rating).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. At the moment, I have done in the categorical way like for the other columns. Let me take a close look at the values in that column. There are several rows of data in my trainingset. BTW, can you give me some idea on how the Gaussian distribution could be done on that column? Thank you

Comment: @VppMan, look for Gaussian Naive Bayes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Gaussian_naive_Bayes

Comment: Just a doubt. Suppose if we fetch the unique values in each column, then assign numerical values(in series like 1,2,3,etc. for each of it) and then update the dataset with these values on the corresponding rows, and if we use the mean&sd calculation to find out the probability like this: http://i.imgur.com/eYY8M4R.png , could it be a good approach or a bad one?

Comment: @VppMan, I don't get how are you gonna preserve difference between close values in that case? If I understand you correctly, it could be the case that 1.3 and 1.4 get assigned totally different numbers like 1 and 322. Besides, what's the meaning of mean and sd in your case?

Comment: Sorry for that. Probably that was a bad idea. I was having too much things going around my head making everything confused. Out of curiosity, do you have any suggestion on a simple way to improve Naive Bayesian? Some simple way so that the performance could slightly be increased? Thank you

Comment: @VppMan It depends on much data you have. Naive Bayes assumes features are independent which is obviously false. So you can add all possible feature (column) pairs to the dataset to model dependent pairs. You can go on with triples but for that you'll need lots of data.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of what to do with the ratings column is the usual answer:  It depends.

I would first try to determine what the numbers for rating really represent.  I would have expected ratings to be integer values like assigning a number of stars for a movie review.  In this case the decimal values suggest that ratings are something else.  Examining the test data should tell you if these are really discrete values already or if they are numbers that could fall anywhere along the number line.  For example, if the only values are 0, 1.1, 2.3, 3.5, 4.2, and 5.6 then handle them just like you would S, M, and L for size.

If the Rating values are really numeric and fall anywhere between 0 and 10 for instance, Can you handle them similar to Temperature in the tennis example.  Temperature could have been measured as a numeric value but has been mapped into groups of Hot, Cool etc.

If grouping doesn't work, they you probably need to reach for some math and calculate the probability based on the distribution of the data.

Lastly, you could try a different algorithm like K Nearest Neighbor

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me take a detailed look at that column in my dataset. Will look into that K Nearest Neighbor algorithm too.